# Why is Linq-To-Sql complaining that a record already exists when I"m using context.table.attach()?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am trying to update all the values of my optimizedSearch record with a completely newly generated POCO without having to manually reset all of the values in my Linq-to-sql object.  To do this I set whatever values I want to be not null and then call:

```
        if (person.xosPodOptimizedSearch == null)
        {
            person.xosPodOptimizedSearch = record;
        }
        else
        {
            context.xosPodOptimizedSearches.Attach(record, true);
            context.Refresh(System.Data.Linq.RefreshMode.KeepCurrentValues, record);
        }
```

The purpose of this code is so that if my `person` record doesn't have an `xosPodOptimizedSearch` record, then add it.  If the person does have one already, I want it updated with whatever values are in the POCO I just created.

However, when this runns and the `.attach(record, true)` is run Linq-to-sql throws an `DuplicateKeyException occurred: Cannot add an entity with a key that is already in use`, which is dumb because I know a record exists, which is why I'm using `attach()` in the first place instead of `.InsertOnSubmit()`.

How can I get data updated 100% with values that I generated, using none of the values in the DB for that record?

Comment: is `record` a new object or an object that is already in the database but you changed the properties of?

Comment: It's a new record instantiated in code via a = new xosPodOptimizedSearches(); call

Comment: shouldn't then `context.SubmitChanges()` be enough to have it enter the database after assigning it to `person.xosPodOptimizedSearch`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292162.aspx

Comment: Nope, if I set `person.xosPodOptimizedSearch` to the newly created record I get the DupliateKeyException` on the `SubmitChanges()` call, which makes sense I guess because it doesn't know to delete the old record

Comment: But the `xosPodOptimizedSearch` is a new object, how can it have a key that already exists in the db? Did you set the Field that represents the Primary Key yourself?

Comment: The table has a 0-1 relationship with the persons table, therefore I do not use an identity ok and instead key it on personid

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, this is my error.  I was confusing Linq-to-sql because earlier in my code I had a stray `record.xosPerson = person;` call, so it only thought the person record was associated with the new record and forgot the old existed.